How does VS Code implement 'accept both' when resolving git conflicts?
I need to implement a custom git merge bash, and I want it like VS Code's 'accept both' function. Does VS Code use some utils or AST parse tool?
Hope someone can tell me some ideas, I need to implement the 'accept both' function in my custom git merge driver bash

What you want is to trace merge-conflict.accept.both in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/merge-conflict/src/commandHandler.ts. It will lead you to applyEdit in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/merge-conflict/src/documentMergeConflict.ts, which seems to just do a simple concatenation. As for how it gets the current and incoming text, see getConflictsOrEmpty in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/merge-conflict/src/documentTracker.ts, which points to scanDocument in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/merge-conflict/src/mergeConflictParser.ts (I.e. it parses the stuff out from the document).

Thx～I'll read these code in detail
